# cómo descargar archivo zip o png almacenado en storage public laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

Estoy utilizando laravel 7 y tengo un sistema dónde los usuarios con el Role Teacher crean unidades y puede agregar un archivo ZIP, Jpg o png,

[image: crud de vista de unidades]

Aquí muestro lo que resulta de mi controlador al mostrar todas las unidades, en la fila del archivo es muy visible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de cómo obtengo los valores de cada unidad mostrado en la lista

[image: código para descargar]

En mi controlador tengo el siguiente código para generar la descarga de cada archivo

[image: ruta para descargar]

Esta es la ruta para descargar el archivo seleccionad pero al descargar el archivo me aparece 404 Not Found, mi archivo se encuentra /storage/app/public/units/

Intente el siguiente código pero sigo con el mismo problema

```
$unit = Storage::disk('public')->findOrFail($unit);
 $tempFile = $unit->file;
 file_put_contents($tempFile, $contents);

  header("Content-type: application/pdf");
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($tempFile));
  readfile($tempFile);
```

ya pude revisar la documentación de laravel incluso con return Storage::disk('public')->download($file->path); pero el la descarga no ocurre

Answer (score 1):

La solución fue

```
 function downloadFile($unit){
    return Storage::disk('public')->response('units/' . $unit->file);
}
```

En el archivo de la vista para descargar el archivo es el siguinte

```
 <td><a href="{{ route("unit.download", $unit) }}">{{ $unit->file }}</a>
```